# Query REST API with image data using CURL

Tags: image, rest, http, curl, get

I have a RESTful API (built on flask) which has to return JSON after receiving an Image file. So this has to be done through GET request with image data. SO, how do i use CURL to query the REST API on image data through GET request? Which format will it be sent to the server for me to retrieve it?

Comment: Don't send bodies with GET requests.

Comment: Hey. Not exactly sure what you mean. Is this the suitable command to send the image data through GET to a restful server? `curl -X GET -H "Content-Type: image/jpeg" --data-binary '@myPicture.jpg' 'server url''` . Should `multipart/form-data` work here?

Comment: @CodeCaster I guess you're saying to avoid sending large data with GET. In that case, can you tell what curl command would work to send an image and retrieve the data from server? Should POST in above command work?